# How to align input(text,date, etc) in adf in both sides

Tags: jsf, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I am trying to align two input-texts in both sides, meaning i want the label part to be aligned in the left side and the value part to be aligned in the right side. I do not want to use the alignment with thE form panel layout beacuase it doesnt do what i want. For the time being i dont want to use css also. Any clues?

Comment: Uh, you don't want to use CSS for styling? How do you want to style then? What exactly is causing your apparent aversion against CSS?

Comment: Nothing but i am using jdeveloper and i was hoping it is done with some configurations...If its not done then i will use css.

Comment: What configurations are you expecting for? Styling in 2.0 web means to use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [page](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/panelFormLayout.jspx) the Sixth one from the top, the label-cell should make everything the way you like.

PS: you will have to use skinning which basically uses CSS!

Comment: I haven't seen the date you posted your answer and hence posted that comment, thanks anyways for updating :)